# Show X has geometric distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let U be (continuous) uniform on (0,1) and 0 < p < 1. Show that
X = ceiling( ln(U)/ln(1-p)), has geometric distribution.

I understand that I need to start with P(U =< x) and I will need to integrate but I am not sure how to apply this to this particular question.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2):

For positive integer $k$ we find:

$$P\left(\lceil\ln\left(U\right)/\ln\left(1-p\right)\rceil>k\right)=P\left(\ln\left(U\right)/\ln\left(1-p\right)>k\right)=P\left(U<\left(1-p\right)^{k}\right)=\left(1-p\right)^{k}$$

Comment: Should I not also end up with it multiplied by p?

Comment: No, because it concerns the CDF (not the PMF).

Comment: For clarity: in my answer it is shown that for positive integer $k$ we have $P(X>k)=(1-p)^k$ or equivalently $F_X(k)=P(X\leq k)=1-(1-p)^k$. Note that RHS is exactly the CDF of geometric distribution.